# Magento FedEx Integration Testing

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, fedex

I have installed FedEx Account number, meter key and all testing purpose parameters in magento's FedEx settings. I am not getting any way to test it. I want to test whether it's working on my localhost so that I can move it in production. Anyone know how to test FedEx on magento? Any example or process for testing magento with FedEx?
Thank you.

Comment: Is there any error message? How do test it?

Comment: Nope, there is no error message. The problem is, I don't know the way to test FedEx integration. How can I test the integration?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a detail instruction how to set up FedEx for Magento:
http://www.cobbconsulting.net/magento-fedex-setup.html

After setting this up I suggest doing a purchase in your Magento shop with FedEx as shipping method. After the purchase if something shows up in your FedEx accunt it probably worked.

Furthermore there is a so called `sandbox mode`. Sandbox mode is for testing only:

- Debug adds additional logging
- See your `<Magento root>/var` or `<Magento root>/var/log` directory for new log file `fedex.log`.
- It shows the request and response of each webservice call and can be very handy for troubleshooting.
- It does not add any additional functionality for the user though.

**On FedEx site there is also a lot to do**, just FYI:

FedEx display two possibilities for communications to their webservice. sandbox or test mode (for setup and debugging) and production mode. at fedex website you will find two types of meter numbers, one for production and one for test. for production you will receive inmediate approval for rate and track calls, but for label generation codes you must go under an approval process by fedex. for testing you can go straigth forward by login into fedex developer system. for that purpose you can follow these steps:

you must log into the fedex developer center: http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/index.html

four steps are required-> 1- Download and read docs , 2-Develop and Test, 3-Certification (only for shipping, pickup services). 4- Move to production.

Comment: Hi, thanks.. I guess it's working. But got one error. Whenever I try to place order after filling all information and choosing payment method as COD, I am getting a popup saying "Please specify shipping method", but in the form, I am unable to see any type of shipping method. Any suggestion? Thanks..